# Animating CAShapeLayer: Do On Completion

Tags: ios, swift, core-animation, cashapelayer

I have a `CAShapeLayer`, whose `strokeEnd` I occasionally update inside of an `NSTimer` loop. Works great, when I call:

```
myPathLayer.strokeEnd += 0.1
```

this path change automatically animates as I want it to. My question is, as this isn't a function call, there isn't a completion block. I'd like to perform another action once this animation completes. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap in with a CATransaction to set a completion block for layer animations.

```
CATransaction.begin()
CATransaction.setCompletionBlock({self.myFunction()})
myPathLayer.strokeEnd += 0.1
CATransaction.commit()
```

Hopefully there is a better way, but this is how I've done it.

Comment: This is a perfectly fine solution in my case. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use CAAnimation delegate method.

```
class Whatever: CAAnimationDelegate { ...
```

then

```
let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: <your_key_path>)
...
animation.delegate = self
```

and use the delegate method:

```
func animationDidStop(_ anim: CAAnimation, finished flag: Bool) {

     if flag { <do_what_you_need_to> }
}
```